# How to prevent someone from entering into a subject you dislike in a conversation?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, politeness, sentence-request

Please suppose in a dialogue between you and your friend he/she is going to start talking about a matter that you feel bad about it and you want to ask them not to enter that subject. Does the sentence below work naturally in this case:

> - We’d better not to enter this subject.

I was wondering if it doesn't sound natural, someone lets me know what is said in this case usually?

Added:

***Case one:***

> **Professor:** We were talking about the theory of relativity during the last session. We also proved these equations (pointing out to the written list which is appeared on the Video Projector curtain.) There are some related equations too that I like to bring them all up and discuss about them, but we are short of time. **We'd better not enter this subject at least now.**

---

***Case two:***

> Maria and Denis are in love. Once when they are talking about their past evidences, Denis starts to talk about one of his ex-girls and it sounds a bit upsetting to Maria to hear about it. She just says: "If you don't mind, **please don't enter this subject please** Denis."

Comment: Please don't go there.

Comment: These are two completely different scenarios and the first example has nothing to do with the question posed in the title.

Comment: @TRomano, but there is only one single sentence in our language which can be freely used in both sentences. For us, they are "too" similar cases.

Comment: @TRomano may I change the subject? Of course if you and other respectable members don't mind. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are dozens of ways to say this.  Could you provide more context?  Do you want to be polite?  Curt?  Dismissive?  Afraid?

For example I could say:

> I'd rather not go there right now. (polite)

or I could say

> I have no interest in discussing that.  (curt)

or

> What an idiotic topic of conversation. (dismissive)

or

> That subject really bothers me and I don't want to talk about it. (fearful)

Again, without more information, the list is very large.

Comment: I will make up a scenario. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Is it possible in my both cases say: "We'd better no go there." in polite way @Andrew?

Comment: "It's better not to go there" is already fairly polite, although a "please" doesn't hurt:  "Please let's not go there."

Comment: Thank you very much @Andrew. Just as the last question to make sure. Does this sentence make sense and sound natural in both cases of mine? I'm asking this question because TRomano mentioned that they are considered as absolutely different cases in English, though they are not at all different in my language.

Comment: No, neither is natural English.  The professor would say "but we had better not get into this subject (just) now".  Maria says to Denis, "please don't talk about your exes."

Comment: I got my answer, but now I cannot catch on to it! Because, I do not understand why "Please don't get into this subject / topic cannot work in my first scenario?! @Andrew could you possibly explain it to me please? :-)

Comment: I disagree with TRomano that these are *completely* separate subjects, but each would say it in a different way.  As I said in English there are many ways to say this, so it's difficult to narrow to a single example that works in any context.

Comment: Just @Andrew does **"We had better not get into this subject"** sound unnatural to be used in my second cas? :)

Answer (score 1):

If a subject is making you feel uncomfortable you can say

> I'd rather not talk about *it* *(right now)*.
>   I don't really want to talk about this.
>   I don't feel comfortable discussing this.

to avoid the subject.  You might also say

> Can we talk about something else.
>   Must we discuss this?

Of course you can suddenly change the subject

> Nice weather we're having today!

to throw off the line of conversation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your ever detailed posts @Peter. They are always useful. Just not to be forgotten, you didn't mention anything about the case when you're short of time. #1 :)

Comment: If you are pressed for time, but feel a long discussion is necessary, you can always say "Sorry, I have to run to *something*. Can we discuss this later when I have more time?" If you don't intent to follow up later than "Can we discuss this later..." will suffice.